# Regex \b word boundary doesn't work with "!"

Tags: python, python-2.7

Not able to search

```
>>> x = "address !152.1.1.1"
>>> y = "!152.1.1.1"
>>> import re
>>> re.search('\\b' +y+ '\\b', x)
```

If I remove "!" then able to search

```
>>> x = "address !152.1.1.1"
>>> y = "152.1.1.1"
>>> re.search('\\b' +y+ '\\b', x)  
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7454a30>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya, you need to use `\B` because there isn't a word boundary `\b` exists between `!` and space.

```
re.search(r'\B' + y+ r'\b', x)
```

`Note:` `\b` matches between a word char and non-word character (vice-versa) whereas `\B` which does the opposite of `\b` which matches between two word characters or two non-word characters. In the first example, there is a non-word boundary `\B` exists between  `!` (*non-word*) which as the starting character of the value present in `y` and the space (*non-word*) which exists before `!`.

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> x = "address !152.1.1.1"
>>> y = "!152.1.1.1"
>>> re.search(r'\B' +y+ r'\b', x)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f0aa3842100>
>>>
```

But in the second example, starting char is `1` (*word char*) and the char exists before `152` (*on the input string*) is `!`(*non-word char*). So here there must be a word boundary `\b`.

Comment: [Say thanks in the form of accept.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: New to stack overflow...So was not aware of "Accept". Done now ! Thanks again.